# Cannot convert from bool to string

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a camera tool that allows the camera to rotate around the player and then reset its position after the arrow key is no longer being held. But when I try to

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CompleteCameraController : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform Player;
public float rotationSpeed = 10f;
public Vector3 offset;

private void Update()
{
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
            transform.RotateAround(Player.transform.position, Vector3.down, Time.deltaTime * 25);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            transform.RotateAround(Player.transform.position, Vector3.up, Time.deltaTime * 25);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            transform.RotateAround(Player.transform.position, Vector3.left, Time.deltaTime * 25);
        }
        if ((Player != null) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            transform.RotateAround(Player.transform.position, Vector3.right, Time.deltaTime * 25);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow !=null))
        {
            transform.LookAt(Player.transform);
        }
    }
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 desiredPosition = Player.position + offset;
        Vector3 smoothedPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, desiredPosition, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.position = smoothedPosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: At what line you are getting an error?

Comment: where u try to convert the bool to a string?

Comment: "But when I try to" then ...?

Comment: I am getting it on line 28

Answer (score 1):

You're probably erroring here:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow !=null))
```

Its unclear why you have the `!= null` portion, remove that and you should be fine

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on the line

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow !=null))
```

You are comparing `KeyCode.LeftArrow` to `null` which does not work, as it is an enum. I think you can safely remove the `!=null` portion and you will be fine.

### Update

After your comment, I think you need to do something like:

```
if ( !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
{
    transform.LookAt(Player.transform);
}
```

Comment: But I want to make it if it is equal to null then it will reset the camera back to the  Player object. So if it is not being held down, it will intern refocus to the Player

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: ty I can figure the rest out from here :D

Comment: @Kingwebbie  If this has resolved your issue, please consider accepting the answer as solution so that the question is resolved.